# apt-get update fails on Ubuntu 22 base docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to upgrade one of our docker base images to the latest stable version of Ubuntu. I have isolated the problem to a simple reproducible case. I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

MAINTAINER mep-dev@zulily.com

# Install java and clean-up
RUN apt-get update
```

When I build it on my local machine, I don't have any problems. However, when I build it on my CICD, I *sometimes* get this error:

> Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get update
> ---> Running in 6ca01b60de64
> Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
> Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
> Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]
> Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
> Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> Reading package lists...
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is not signed.
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
> W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
> W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is not signed.
> E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
> E: Sub-process returned an error code
> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100

If I comment out `RUN apt-get update`, then it succeeds, and I can enter the container and see that `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg` and `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg` do exist and have read for all permissions:

> root@b778220b39d8:/# ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
> total 8
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2794 Mar 26  2021 ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1733 Mar 26  2021 ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg

I also checked the parent directories, and they have r-x at least for all.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300627/apt-rejects-keyrings-in-etc-apt-trusted-gpg-d-on-ubuntu-18-04) might be related, but why would the file have the correct structure when the base image is used in one environment and not another?

Update:

By using `--pull`, I can see the exact image it's using.

> $ docker build --pull -t $EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY_ARN .
> Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:22.04
> 22.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
> Digest: sha256:b6b83d3c331794420340093eb706a6f152d9c1fa51b262d9bf34594887c2c7ac
> Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:22.04
> ---> 27941809078c

This is the same sha and image id that I see when building locally, which works.

I am not having the same problem with ubuntu:20.04.

Comment: Is there any chance your CICD environment has a stale version of the image? Can you explicitly `docker pull ubuntu:22.04` before trying to build your image?

Comment: @larsks I think you have the right answer. Want to make it an answer so you can get the reputation points for it?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about your CI/CD environment?

Comment: which version of Docker do you have ?

Comment: Notice the line 

    W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.

Try with `--secufrity-opt seccomp:unconfined` which may have security implications but does address the issue.

```
$ docker run --security-opt seccomp:unconfined -it ubuntu:22.04
```

references:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1889311
https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/183

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I cannot run \`apt update\` inside a fresh ubuntu:22.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941032/why-i-cannot-run-apt-update-inside-a-fresh-ubuntu22-04)

Answer (score 36):

After spending half a day trying to fix the Ubuntu images (which aren't broken) I have eventually started debugging the host.

It's a `docker` problem. Ubuntu makes use of syscalls for better key security, which Docker didn't support yet. **The solution is to update docker**... or use nerdctl, runc or something similar.

Instead of `apt` getting the message that the syscalls aren't supported, **it gets the message that permission is denied, which results in the confusing error messages.**

You could technically patch ubuntu to be less secure, and to work with older docker, but that is sadly not a long term solution.

[This](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/42681) is the PR that fixes it in the Docker(/moby) project. Note that the problem may occur in other Docker images (or other software in Ubuntu) as well, since it is ultimately caused by [a change in glibc](https://patchwork.sourceware.org/project/glibc/patch/20210601145516.3553627-2-hjl.tools@gmail.com/) that was incompatible with the default seccomp profile of Docker.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I solved it by updating docker and docker-compose .

Comment: What version of docker did you end up with when you upgraded?

Comment: I also got this bug with Docker Engine 19 and found it works on Docker Engine 20.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was having the same issue running Dind with version 19.0.2 in my Gitlab Ci/CD pipeline. I updated docker to 24.0.7 and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

A very dirty but probably acceptable hack for some docker hacking is this:

```
apt update --allow-insecure-repositories
```

Which just ignores the signatures. The errors get still printed, but the package repository is updated, and you can install new packages afterwards. Even though you get warned and asked if that is really what you want to do.

Comment: This leads to other errors down the road. So finally I took the bullet and ran "apt update; apt upgrade" on the host system, which updated to the latest docker where this problem was solved...

Answer (score 4):

Exactly same problem

> Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> Reading package lists...
> [91mW: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.

Dockerfile (simple how to reproduce) docker-version: 18.x or 19.03/

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
```

With latest Docker version 20.10.9, i did not see the issue.

some of the options tried to tshoot:

1. sed -i 's/jammy/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
2. RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
   this fails with with another child-issue
   gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation

SO, solutions seems to be either update docker-version or use a tagged image where it has worked previously.

Comment: Same issue. If you don't want to update docker version (or you cant), you can use tagged image for `ubuntu:20.04` which will run `apt-get update` without complaints.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference a docker image by name, Docker only checks to see if it exists locally or not -- it doesn't check for updates. So if there is *already* a version of the named image available, it will use that even though it might be stale. I suspect that's what you're seeing: some of your CI nodes must have a cached version of the image that has problems.

There are a few ways of dealing with this:

1. Explicitly `docker pull ubuntu:22.04` before calling `docker run`; this will pull down a newer version of the image if one exists.
2. Add `--pull always` to your `docker run` command line. This accomplishes the same thing but without requiring an extra command execution.
3. Reference an image by digest rather than by tag. If you use an image reference like this:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu@sha256:bace9fb0d5923a675c894d5c815da75ffe35e24970166a48a4460a48ae6e0d19
   ```

Then docker will use *that exact image*. You can find the image digests on docker hub.

Comment: Thanks. --pull helped me with some chaotic results I was seeing with my actual use case, which involves an intermediate base image I create myself and am frequently updating as I work out these issues. However, none of those three approaches fixed the issue. I am editing the question with my additional findings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Travis CI.

The default host environment is Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 at the time of writing: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/linux/.

After changing it to Jammy 22.04, the problem is fixed.

In `.travis.yml`

```
dist: jammy
```

This host environment has the updated Docker version to support newer base images.